# What AMD notation like r7-2700x means?

Tags: amd-ryzen

As far as I understood, the r=Ryzen, but what about:

1. 7
2. 2700
3. X

Moreover, tha same applies to the mobo, like AMD X370, AMD X470, AMD X399 and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does AMD notation like r7-2700x mean?

- `r` is Brand (Ryzen)
- `7` is Segement (Enthusiast/Prosumer)
- `2` is Generation
- `7` is Performance Level (Enthusiast/Prosumer)
- `00` is Model Number
- `x` is Power Suffix (High Permance with XFR)

[image]

Source [Here's how to make sense of AMD Ryzen naming | ZDNet](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-make-sense-of-amd-ryzen-naming/)

Comment: Thanks. And what about the mobo?

Comment: @user840718 - What about the motherboard?

Comment: @user840718 I can't find a definitive guide for the motherboard names. AMD seem to have changed their naming scheme at regular intervals ...